# JSON data fetched using API not being displayed using JQuery and Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

So, I am creating this webapp that utilizes the BetterDoctor's API to fetch a list of doctors related to a particular practice (like cardiology).

I am using Handlebars, JQuery, HTML, and JS to do this.

[A screenshot of what the code looks like in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJMCY.png)

When I try and run the code on the browser, the data can't be seen in the template as defined in the HTML page under the {{#data}} tag. Whilst inspecting the page and taking a look at the browser console, I couldn't find anything wrong since the console.log was returning the correct url that had the required JSON data from which data was meant to be fetched from.

Any help regarding this issue would be of great help and very much appreciated.

Here's a pen containing the code:https://codepen.io/sandeeprao/pen/OzbQJY?editors=1010

You can see the error

Here's my HTML

```
<div>
  name a speciality: <input type="text" id="speciality">
<br></br>
  enter state (in short form): <input type="text" id="state">
  <br></br>
  lattitude: <input type="text" id="lat" value="">
  longitude: <input type="text" id="lon" value="">
</div>

<div id="content-placeholder"></div>
<script id="docs-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
 <table>
  <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Bio</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#data}}
  <tr>
      <td><p>{{profile.first_name}} {{profile.last_name}}</p><br>
      <td>{{profile.title}}</td>
      <td>{{profile.bio}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/data}}
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </script>
```

Here is the JS file for it:

```
  var base_url = 'https://api.betterdoctor.com/2016-03-01/practices?';
  function go2(){
  var speciality = document.getElementById('speciality').value;
  var state = document.getElementById('state').value;
  var url_search = {
  name: speciality,
  location: state,
  user_location: '',
  skip: 0,
  limit: 10,
  user_key: 'CODE_SAMPLES_KEY_9d3608187'
   }
 console.log(speciality);
 console.log(state);
 var url = base_url + jQuery.param( url_search );
 console.log(url)
  $.get(url, function (data) {
  // data: { meta: {<metadata>}, data: {<array[Practice]>} }
  var template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById('docs-
  template').innerHTML);
  document.getElementById('content-placeholder').innerHTML = template(data);
   });
  }
```

Comment: Don't use variable names with numbers at the end. When you start numbering variables, this is a good indicator that you actually want to use an array.

Comment: And **don't** build URLs like that. Ever. This is bad and wrong. jQuery has a helper function for building URLs. Read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: Please try to narrow your problem down to a [mcve]. For example, does the problem have anything to do with P5.js? If not, get rid of the P5.js code and the [tag:p5.js] tag. Use hard-coded values wherever possible. Post a link to a CodePen or a JSFiddle that shows the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply! I did follow your advice on removing the p5.js parts and made it purely JS. Regarding the CodePen, I created a pen with the above code, here's the link: https://codepen.io/sandeeprao/pen/OzbQJY?editors=1010

Comment: @Tomalak, I have used an array instead of numbering the variables. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The second tip is much more important in this case. Numbered variables are bad, but building URLs by concatenating some strings is worse. You don't even need an array here. Use a base URL (up to and excluding the `?`) and then object with keys and values. jQuery will convert it to a full, properly formatted URL automatically. Look at the documentation and examples for `$.get()`. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#entry-examples - It will even be much more readable this way because you don't need *any* of your temporary helper variables.

Comment: @Tomalak, Sure! Thanks for the help! I did accordingly using the jQuery.param() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been sorted out. I figured out that there was a problem in the handlebars code and interpreting the JSON format of the API's result.

```
<td>{{#doctors}}
    {{profile.first_name}}{{profile.last_name}}{{/doctors}}</td>
    <td>{{doctors.profile.first_name}} {{doctors.profile.last_name}}</td>
```

That's the fix!